# Pass Id to controller through ng-include

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

How do I get the id from my view to my controller in an ng-include?

I have the following view:

```
@model Nybroe.FightPlan.Sql.Model.EventRecord
@{
var eventId = Model.Id;
}
<div ng-app="tournamentApp">
    <div ng-include src="'/Apps/Modules/FightCard/FightCard.html'">
        <div ng-init="id = @eventId"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ng-controller is defined in the FightCard.html template.

And I am trying to get the id parameter into my controller by so:

```
$scope.evId = $scope.id
```

But it turns up undefined.

I hope you guys can help me out! :)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use object notation X.id and it should work. Your id is probably in an isolated scope

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it. The solution is to use ng-init:

View:

```
    <div ng-app="tournamentApp" ng-controller="FightCardController">
      <input type="hidden" ng-init="evId='@eventId'" ng-model="evId" />
        <div id="@eventId" ng-include src="'/Apps/Modules/FightCard/FightCard.html'">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.eventId = $scope.evId;
```